# Need help capturing error messages in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am trying to capture the users in the local Administrators group from multiple servers on the network.  I originally started with a script I found that does an WMI call, but all of those are blocked on the network.

I finally got the following to work, but When I get an error, it gives the Powershell error, and I would like to simplify it by just giving the short answer such as  "Access is Denied" or "WinRM cannot process the request.", etc...  I have to turn the report in to users who are non-technical.

I would like to capture the sentence following the **following error message :** to the period.

If there is a better way of doing this, or the output, I am open to suggestions.

Thanks for your help

```
$computerlist = get-content "C:\ServerList.txt"


ForEach ($computer in $computerList)
    {
    &{$computer 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Get-LocalGroupMember -Group administrators} |
        Select-Object Name,PrincipalSource|Format-table -AutoSize 
    Write-Output " "} 2>&1 >>.\output.txt
    
    }
```

> [XXXXXXX] Connecting to remote server XXXXXXX failed with the following error message : **WinRM cannot process the request.** The following error occurred while using
> Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer XXXXXXX. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more
> information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
> + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (EPICSOAPT:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionStateBroken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerList -ScriptBlock { 
  Get-LocalGroupMember -Group administrators | Select-Object Name, PrincipalSource 
} 2>&1 | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) { # an error
    # Extract the substring of interest from the error message and prepend 
    # the computer name.
    # Write the result as a *warning*
    # Note: Warnings are sent to a different output stream,
    #       which in this case means that all warnings print *before* 
    #       Format-Table's output.
    Write-Warning ("$($_.TargetObject ): " + (($_ -split ' : ')[1] -split '\.')[0] + '.')
  }
  else { # an output object, pass it through
    $_ 
  }
} | Format-Table -GroupBy PSComputerName -AutoSize > .\output.txt
```

- It is better to pass the *list* of computers to `Invoke-Command` in a *single* call, which causes these computers to be targeted *in parallel*.

  - Note: The output from the target computers is *not* guaranteed to arrive in *input order*, but you could insert a [`Sort-Object PSComputerName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) pipeline segment in order to sort the results alphabetically by computer name.
- As in your approach `2>&1` is used to merge the error stream (`2`) into the success (`1`) stream.
- In the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) script block, `-is`, the [type(-inheritance) / interface test operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators) is used to detect errors ([`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord)) instances among the input objects.

  - If such an instance is found, the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) is used to extract the part of the error message of interest, and the computer name is prepended.
  - [`Write-Warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-warning) is used to emit the error message in a visually conspicuous manner; Note that warnings are sent to a different [output stream (#3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), which in this case means that all warnings print *before* the success output formatted by `Format-Table`.
  - If you wanted to emit the warnings *after*, you'd have to collect the strings in an array (or list) and output them in a separate statement afterwards.
- [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)'s `-GroupBy` parameter is used to *group* the formatted success output objects by the `.PSComputerName` property, which is implicitly added by [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) and contains the name of the source computer.

  - Note that both the `.PSComputerName` property and the other added property, `.RunspaceId` are *included* in the table output by default.  You can avoid inclusion of `PSComputerName` by adding the `-HideComputerName` switch to the `Invoke-Command` call; however, the `RunspaceId` property is still included. To avoid that, use `Format-Table`'s `-Property` parameter to pass an explicit list of property names to display. (Another, more convenient but more expensive option is to use `-HideComputerName`, and insert a `Select-Object * -Exclude RunspaceId` command into the pipeline, before the `Format-Table` call).

---

**Sample output** (assumes that successfully retrieved objects have properties `one`, `two`, and `three`; note how the warning about a failed connection prints first):

```
WARNING: server2: WinRM cannot complete the operation.

   PSComputerName: server1

one two three PSComputerName RunspaceId
--- --- ----- -------------- ----------
  1   2     3 server1        29b0bc1e-cf7f-4d9b-b267-86deff2b7ed0
  4   5     6 server1        ab2ed6a9-3fba-4083-b13e-b43617048ecf

   PSComputerName: server3

one two three PSComputerName RunspaceId
--- --- ----- -------------- ----------
  7   8     9 server3        39b0bc1e-cf7f-4d9b-b267-86deff2b7ed1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `try/catch` block with `-ErrorAction Stop` with the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet.

`ErrorAction Stop` forces the error to be thrown as an Exception which can be caught with the try / catch block and process the error message however you want.

```
try { 
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName test -ScriptBlock { 
    Write-output "hello" 
  } -ErrorAction Stop 
} 
catch { 
  Write-Output "Error Occured: $($_)" 
}

// prints normal output: 
Error Occured: [test] Connecting to remote server test failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer test. Verify that the co
mputer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```